# Reverse engineer visualizations to compactly extract underlying data

Tags: interpolation, sampling

**TL;DR**

> How to implement in mathematica a tool such as
> [WebPlotDigitizer](https://automeris.io/WebPlotDigitizer/) by Ankit Rohatgi
> which would allow us to trace automatically curves
> from either (randomly ordered) data or imported images.

[image]

**Context**

As a Follow up of this [question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEbt2.png) and both [nice answers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/250669/1089)
given there, I am after an algorithm *which could (as automatically as possible) trace the different sets of curves* in plots such as these (calorific curves
of distribution of intermediate black holes in a Galactic centre).

[image]

The challenge is that these points are found by some complex optimisation routine and are over-numerous in places. So I am interested in resampling the different curves. **Note importantly that the curves cross** (e.g. near (-0.015,2)).
This can be seen as a reverse engineering problem  to extract a compact re-parametrisation of the different curves (hence the link to [WebPlotDigitizer](https://automeris.io/WebPlotDigitizer/)).

**Question**

> How can one achieve the automatic curve matching/ sampling procedure?

---

**Attempt**

Let me define a toy problem as follows: let me produce two curves:

```
data = Flatten[{Table[{x, Sin[x^2/15]}, {x, 0, 20, 0.01}],
    Table[{x, 1 + Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 20, 0.1}]}, 1];
```

and draw random points from those.

```
pts = RandomChoice[data, Length[data]];

ListPlot[pts]
```

[image]

Note that on purpose the sampling is not the same for the two curves.
One could imaging one of two situations: either have access to `pts` or `ListPlot[pts]//Image` (but obviously not `data`).

Following this (excellent) [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/250675/1089) I can get a good resampling as follows:

```
tour = Last[FindShortestTour[pts]];
tourPts = Extract[pts, List /@ tour];
peaks = Ordering[EuclideanDistance @@@ Partition[tourPts, 2, 1], -2];
{firstCurve, secondCurve} = 
  TakeDrop[RotateLeft[tourPts, peaks[[1]]], Abs[Subtract @@ peaks]];


np[f_][u_, dt_] := u + dt/Norm[f'[u]]
equallySpacedPts[pts_, dt_] := 
 With[{bsf = BSplineFunction[pts]}, 
  bsf /@ Most[NestWhileList[np[bsf][#, dt] &, 0, # < 1 &]]]

equallySpacedPts[#,0.25]&/@{firstCurve,secondCurve}//ListLinePlot
```

[image]

**BUT**  It is clear that the two curves are not (always) properly matched, e.g. near `x=3` or `x=15`.

I understand that this is not a trivial matter, but it should be IMHO of general interest for mathematica to be able to   stand up to this challenge with minimum manual input (?).

---

*Comment*:

It might be possible to use a R package via [digitizeR](https://github.com/ankitrohatgi/digitizeR)
and [R integration](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-9/built-in-integration-with-r/) in Mathematica, but obviously a
standalone implementation would be preferable.

Comment: Take a look at this answer for (maybe) some helpful clues. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/149244/is-there-a-way-to-sort-nsolve-solution-roots-automatically/149426#149426

Comment: Also this one, which uses the previous one's result. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/146193/the-solutions-of-system-of-equations-are-not-continuous/149756#149756

Comment: @MikeY sounds promising indeed. Would you care writing an answer?

Comment: Is the big plot a single curve that spirals around, or two curves spiraling, or a set of individual ellipses? Checking...

Comment: @MikeY the initial plot is only illustrative: it is a 3D set of tilted circles

Comment: Do you have the data?

Comment: The data is for instance: `data = Flatten[{Table[{x, Sin[x^2/15]}, {x, 0, 20, 0.01}],
    Table[{x, 1 + Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 20, 0.1}]}, 1];`

Comment: Will the sampling rate of one be an integer or rational multiple of the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach that seems to work reasonably well:

```
cleaned = DeleteDuplicates@SortBy[First]@pts;
curves = {};
(pt \[Function] Module[
     {best},
     best = MinimalBy[#[[2]] &]@MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], VectorAngle[(#[[-1]] - pt), Subtract @@ #[[-2 ;;]]], EuclideanDistance[pt, #[[-1]]]} &]@curves;
     If[best === {} || best[[1, 3]] > 1,
      AppendTo[curves, {pt - {0.1, 0}, pt}],
      AppendTo[curves[[best[[1, 1]]]], pt]
      ]
     ]) /@ cleaned;
curves = Rest /@ curves;

ListPlot@curves
```

[image]

We first sort the points by their x-coordinate and remove any duplicates. We now initialize a list of collected curves (initially empty). Then, we go through the points one by one and find the curve where adding the new point would cause the smallest change in direction (where "change in direction" is computed using `VectorAngle`). The idea here is that we'd like to avoid sharp corners in the lines if possible. If `curves` was empty, or the existing lines are all too far away (this threshold might need to be adjusted depending on the curves at hand), we create a new entry in `curves`. We add two points to make sure the angle computation doesn't fail (this point is later removed). Otherwise, we add the point to the best match.

The biggest issue currently is the detection of new lines: The current method based on the distance to existing curves might not always work as expected if the points are spaced too far apart on some of the curves.

Comment: Nice! Thank you for this elegant and short answer. I will let others a chance to give alternative answers and hope to motivate WRI to integrate a generic solution in upcoming release of Mathematica which would possibly integrate some of the code provided by   WebPlotDigitizer (?).

Comment: In other words, I am personally interested in your answer but I think being able to do this from images should prove generally useful.